# Strange color-coding in PuTTY

Tags: c++, putty

I have noticed that one of the .cpp files I have in a Linux server that I use PuTTY to get to is highlighted green, as it seems it should be. I have another .cpp file that is just gray, like normal text. I remember this happening a while back but I never looked into it. Now I'm thinking that there's a relation to the fact that the gray .cpp was one that I created myself in Notepad++ and then saved to that directory. The green one was one from my professor that I downloaded in a tar file and uncompressed into the directory. The reason I'm saying this is because I think that was the pattern for the last time I noticed this as well.

Any reason why this would be happening?
Thanks!

Comment: Could be an enclosing `/*` comment, or `#if`. Try to recreate the color coding with other code. Note that syntax coloring depends on the editor and its configuration; as Francis Glassbarrow once remarked, the nice thing about it is that you can configure it to show comments as white on white.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are talking about the colored output of `ls` command on Linux, which is a question not specific to C++ or PuTTY.

By default, the gray color is used for normal files and the green color for executable files. If you type `ls -l`, it will print one file by line along with some information about them. The file permissions is encoded as a sequence of letters and dashes, such as:

```
-rwxr-xr-x
-rw-r--r--
```

The letter `x` means the file is marked as executable. A file is often marked as executable when transported from different a system, such as from Windows (NTFS) to Linux (usually ext3 or ext4).

A C++ source file (`.cpp`) is a text file and cannot be executed (it must be compiled and linked to turn into a program), so it usually doesn't make sense to have that file marked as executable, i.e., it should be gray, not green. You can use the following command to remove the execution permission:

```
chmod a-x FILE
```

which means to change mode (`chmod`) of `FILE` for all (`a`) users - owner, owner's group and others - and remove (`-`) the execution (`x`) permission. You can also remove that permission by other forms (such as using octal values) or using a file browser.

Comment: Awesome thanks for adding in that bit about files being marked as executables from different system. That's handy to know.